# Listen to multiple database references

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a project in which I need to listen to multiple database locations at once.

```
{
  "A": [data-a],
  "B": [data-b],
  "C": [data-c]
}
```

Whenever anything gets changed, added or deleted at location `A`, `B` or `C` I want to display the action which happened inside a `ListView` in Android.

For one location I have been able to achieve this by adding the following code to my project.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("A");
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    //Child got added
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    //Child got changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Child got removed
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    //Child got moved
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    //Some error happened
    }
});
```

Now to my question. Do I need multiple listeners for each location or can I somehow get notified about all changes in a simpler way?

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/join|sort:date/firebase-talk/DKnBnI0bqoI/YMrp-L1hBgAJ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to add multiple references and child listeners. Firebase has no concept of unions, joins, or other operators present in SQL databases. There is a 1:1 relationship between collections of data you want to retrieve and the references / listeners you use to access them. You cannot use wildcards or other mechanisms to access more than one data collection at a time from a single call.

Comment: Alright! But isn't it ambiguous to add , For suppose 3 child listener for 3 db references.
Do i need to implement 1:1 Child-Listener for every db reference?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ambiguous, but this is standard Firebase practice. If you look at FirebaseUI you will even find "indexed" data source implementations that do exactly this - make one master query, then for each child, obtain that child's ref separately.